# Sending GET to server gives no response (but status returned)

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, xmlhttprequest, response

I'm sending an ajax request to my server that updates some data there. Request is sent with jquery's `get` function. On success I'd like te perform some action, but unfortunately whole operation fails since server gives no response, even though firebug clearly shows 200 status:

[image]
What more, when I enter this address with browser, also everything looks fine. Any ideas why it may not be working properly ? Here's my js:

```
    $(".interests-delete").live("click", function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('title');
        var user_id = "100000717262400";

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://dev1.gecoloco.com/rte/ilike.php?",
            data: "u=" + user_id + "&d=" + id,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response, status){
                alert(status);
                console.log(response);
                getLikes();
            }
        });
        return false;            
    });
```

Comment: Try omitting the question mark from the end of the `url` parameter.

Comment: without the question mark the url changed to ...php?u= , without the additional '&'. But the problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely due to "same origin policy' which mandates your html should come from the same domain to which ajax call is issued. Try loading your html page not from file system but through the same server serving the ajax calls. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your url looks a bit funny there.  The part: "?&u=..." should be "?u=..."

Comment: it looks like jq adds this additional `&` sign. Still link works with this one added : http://dev1.gecoloco.com/rte/ilike.php?u=100000717262400&d=2

Comment: @mastodon , paste the url directly on browser and see whats happening??

Comment: checked on both chrome and ff and I'm getting json response. So what am I missing ?

Comment: @mastodon , is client and server both on the same server , otherwise it may be a cross domain request issue...

Comment: @mastodon , if that is the issue search for that..there are lot of threads in this SO itself

Comment: goddamn again cross site issue ? :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something is wrong with your success function. It is possible you are getting a response but your javascript is crashing somewhere in your function.

Comment: but the function on success is not even fired, since there's no actual response.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this before when I opened a page from the local file system in my browser, e.g. `file:///C:/Users/Eason/Desktop/mailer/index.html`.

When this page attempts to make an AJAX request, it would cause that problem. When it's published on a web server (e.g. Tomcat) it would work.

This is a security restriction in the browser to prevent unsafe cross-domain traffic.